# Hyperledger fabric : unable to create channel on raspberry pi 4 with Raft ordering service

Tags: raspberry-pi, hyperledger-fabric, channel, raft

I am trying to setup an hyperledger fabric network on a Raspberry Pi 4.

My version of Fabric is 1.4.6.

I am able to create a network running with a solo ordering service, but when I try with Raft, I can't create the channel.

I am following the byfn tutorial (I didn't change anything to the files). I type the command ./byfn.sh up -o etcdraft -v and I obtain this error :

2020-05-12 12:39:04.789 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 047 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2020-05-12 12:39:04.992 UTC [cli.common] readBlock -> INFO 048 Got status: &{NOT_FOUND}
2020-05-12 12:39:05.004 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 049 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: timeout waiting for channel creation
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

I also tried to do exactly the same thing on a virtual machine and its works perfectly so I believe it is linked to th Raspberry Pi.

Someone can help please ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your internet connection! If your internet connection is working perfectly then clean if any other docker containers are running using the following commands:

docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)

after you delete leftover(if any) docker images then bring your network down. It's ideal to bring the network down before bringing up network. Type below command:

./byfn.sh down